# How to sum pandas dataframe by specific column without changing other columns?

Tags: pandas, sum, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this one

```
ddf = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a', 'a', 'c', 'c'],
    'B': ['b', 'b', 'd', 'd'],
    'C': [1, 2, 3, 4]
})

ddf


    A   B   C
0   a   b   1
1   a   b   2
2   c   d   3
3   c   d   4
```

And i would like to have the following result by summing through column C:

```
    A   B   C
0   a   b   3
1   c   d   7
```

How to do that in pandas ?

Comment: Is there groupby functionality in pandas?

Comment: `ddf.groupby(['A','B'],as_index=False)['C'].sum()`

Comment: You can also use: `ddf.groupby(['A','B'],as_index=False).agg({'C':'sum'})`